# not able to pass Keras Generator image to face recognition

Tags: python, keras, face-recognition, data-augmentation

I am using Keras to generate pictures to feed face_recognition package.

the following code I used to read and prepare the picture to be passed to the generator

```
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
imageGen = aug.flow(image, batch_size=1)
```

then for the generated image is used as follow:

```
for gimage in imageGen:
   face_recognition.face_locations(gimage, 'cnn')
```

> RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image.

I tried to solve the issue by using `squeeze` before passing the generated picture; but also it did not work

```
gimage = np.squeeze(gimage, axis=0)
```

Comment: What is the gimage.dtype?

Comment: gimage type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` @akazuko

Comment: @akazuko, gimage.dtype:  float32. I think the problem is here. the image must be int. thank you for your question. I will try to change

Comment: What about gimage values? Can you also add truncated gimage also in the question?

Comment: Cool, that's what I was trying to validate

Comment: @akazuko, what do you mean "truncated gimage"?

Comment: I meant some part of the gimage ndarray. It would have helped in checking the type of values. But you mentioned that already

Comment: thank you @akazuko, please write the answer for it as to the datatype validity and I will accept it

Comment: the data type must be `uint8` not `float32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check gimage ndarray's value dtype. It should be `uint8` and as per the error it looks like currently it is `float32`